# How to replace text in a google spreadsheet cell with another text using if condition

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I want to know how to change value / text in a spreadsheet cell with another
I tried this `"=IF(C15="100%",high,Medium)"` - but no luck.

- If i change the value in a cell to 100% the cell should change "100%"
  TO "High".
- If i change the value in a cell to 50% or 20% or 30% the
  cell should change "50%" TO "Medium".
- If i change the value in a
  cell to 0 the cell should change "0" TO "low".

Note: the cell should be editable...

Answer (score 2):

Use Number → Format → Percent on the toolbar to format the values as percentages. It's better to use a range to map them.

```
=IF(C15>0.5, "High", IF(C15>=0.2, "Medium", "Low"))
```

Explanation: If cell value is greater than 50% it maps as High, else if it's greater than equal to 20% it maps as Medium, else it maps as Low.

You need the quotes as it's a word as opposed to a number or a reference to a cell.

Comment: IF i paste this code inside C15.. it shows #REF! Error! i wanted  to apply the function in C15.

Comment: Format → Conditional Formatting to change the cell's colour according to the rules like red for High, yellow for medium, green for low. However it can't change the text in-place.

Answer (score 0):

When you write 100% or 99% in a cell it automatically formats it as a share, i.e. 1 and 0.99, respectively.

Try the formula `=if(C15=1,"High",IF(C15=0,"Low","Medium"))`

Comment: IF i paste this code inside C15.. it shows #REF! Error! i wanted  to apply the function in C15.

Comment: You can't make a function reference to it self. I am assuming that your input, say 100%, is in cell `C15` and that this formula is placed in any other cell but `C15`

Comment: Any other method to change value?? in excel we can use icon set in same cell. i want a similar effect.. means if i change value, the value should hide & show a icon or another text..

Comment: I don't have a solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this very old unsolved thread while looking for something else.
I believe i have the solution, so I'm posting it with a 6 years delay.

In Format -> Numbers -> More Number Formats -> Custom Number Formats, type in:

`[=1]"High";[>0]"Medium";"Low"`

This way, when you put in the value 50% inside the cell, the value is shown as "Medium".

Hopefully this helps someone!